# How to use environment variable in github action job/continue-on-error section?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

If I have the following section in my github action workflow yaml:

```
env:
  fullySupportedScalaVersions: "2.13.6"

  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    continue-on-error: ${{ contains(env.fullySupportedScalaVersions, matrix.scalaVersion) }}
```

I receive an error message like this:

```
Invalid workflow file : .github/workflows/main.yml#L38
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 38, Col: 24): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 10 within expression: contains(env.fullySupportedScalaVersions, matrix.scalaVersion) .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 38, Col: 24): Unexpected value '${{ contains(env.fullySupportedScalaVersions, matrix.scalaVersion) }}'
```

How do I solve or circumvent this problem?

The above is observed in the following workflow:
https://github.com/tek/splain/blob/6b12e57954aae0852e9b948e12ef5637c478b53d/.github/workflows/main.yml

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to the syntax used on the `continue-on-error:` field.

I made it worked updating it to

```yaml
continue-on-error: ${{ contains( '${{ env.FULLY_SUPPORTED_SCALA_VERSIONS }}', '${{ matrix.scalaVersion }}') }}
```

So that the workflow didn't return the error anymore.

- Here is the [related workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/splain/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml)
- Here is the [related workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/splain/actions/runs/1473824287)

*It returns an error during the execution, but it is for another reason not related to this topic.*

---

From what I understood, the `continue-on-error` filed doesn't work the same way as the `if` field for expressions.

For example, when you use expressions in an `if` conditional, you do not need to use the expression syntax `${{ }}` because GitHub automatically evaluates the `if` conditional as an expression.

But it's not the case with `continue-on-error`, expressions don't seem to be automatically detected by Github, so you need to add the brackets back. Moreover, Github didn't recognised `env.FULLY_SUPPORTED_SCALA_VERSIONS` directly there, so I had to add brackets here as well (probably due to the field specifications).

Comment: thanks a lot! will post your answer to issue tracker after validation